# MongoDB doesn't save document when timestamps are initialized in struct

Tags: mongodb, rust, bson, actix-web

I am having a very weird issue when trying to save a data in Mongodb by the Rust driver. This is my struct

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
struct Info {
    #[serde(rename = "_id", skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    id: Option<bson::oid::ObjectId>,
    name: String,
    created_at: i64,
    updated_at: i64,
}
```

And this is my actix route handler function

```rust
async fn post_request(info: web::Json<Info>, data: web::Data<State>) -> impl Responder {
    let name: &str = &info.name;
    let document = Info {
        id: None,
        name: name.to_string(),
        created_at: Utc::now().timestamp_millis(),
        updated_at: Utc::now().timestamp_millis(),
    };
    // Convert to a Bson instance:
    let serialized_doc = bson::to_bson(&document).unwrap();
    let doc = serialized_doc.as_document().unwrap();
    let collection = data.client.database("test1").collection("users");
    let result = collection.insert_one(doc.to_owned(), None).await.unwrap();
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(result).await
}
```

I am getting the `Utc` struct by `chrono` crate.
When i am trying to save the data in MongoDB by hitting the route, It doesn't gets saved. But, oddly, when i comment out the `created_at` and `updated_at` in struct and handler, it gets saved. If i don't use structs and try to save it as a raw document, by storing `created_at` and `updated_at` in variables, then also it gets saved, but not by structs. I am new to rust so maybe i am doing something wrong. Please help

Comment: Try `created_at: new Date(Utc::now().timestamp_millis())`

Comment: What's the error when it fails saving?

Comment: @CodesInChaos it doesn't throws any error. It just doesn't work.